# Textbox in gridarrange

Tags: r, pdf, gridextra, gplots

I am arranging two graphs on a pdf using `grid.arrange`.

I would like to have a text box between the title and the first plot to add some information on the graphs themselves possibly editing in in rich text.

What is the best solution for that?
I would ideally produce it in R directly and printing it out with the rest of the plot.

Any idea?

To use a standard example of grid.arrange

```
pl = replicate(3, ggplot(), FALSE)
grid.arrange(grobs = pl)
```